# Gtfs database on Mysql - slow query when search for routes in area

Tags: mysql, sql, gtfs

I'm currently running a **mysql database** with **GTFS data** loaded in it.
I'm trying to **get all routes in a specific area** (5 km from a center point).
The idea is to query stops for a specific area, then from stops go thought stop_times and trips to get the routes.
My problem is that stop_times table is really big, I can't find the right SQL query to **avoid a slow query**.

I've tried a normal inner join query, then subquery with distinct key:

```
SELECT routes.* 
FROM routes 
WHERE routes.route_id IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT trips.route_id FROM trips WHERE trips.trip_id IN
(SELECT DISTINCT stop_times.trip_id FROM stop_times WHERE stop_times.stop_id IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT stops.stop_id FROM stops WHERE ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(9.191383,45.464210), stops.coordinate) < 5000)))
```

Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

try avoid IN cluase and use INNER JOIN instead

```
SELECT routes.* 
FROM routes 
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT DISTINCT trips.route_id 
  FROM trips
  INNER JOIN  ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT stop_times.trip_id 
    FROM stop_times 
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT stops.stop_id 
      FROM stops 
      WHERE ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(9.191383,45.464210), stops.coordinate) < 5000
    ) t1 on t1.stop_id = stop_times.stop_id 
  ) t2 ON t2.trip_id = trips.trip_id 
) t3 ON routes.route_id = t3.route_id
```

and be sure you have index  on

```
table routes  column route_id
table trips column trip_id 
table stop_times column stop_id
```

Comment: your query is great when the 'WHERE' clause contains an equal condition (''WHERE stop_id = 'abcd'"). While with 'ST_DISTANCE' the query never respond. I've also tried to add a SPATIAL INDEX on stops.coordinate. The other indexes already exists.

Comment: without a valid data sample   I can't imagine a solution .. probaly the query can be refatcored  better .. but i don't know your table shema and the logic for your goal  ..